# Cannot find symbol methods when compiling?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

For some reason my tester class is not recognizing the methods in my method class. Help? I get errors such as "cannot find symbol method digitToBarCode(int)" and "cannot find symbol method checkDigit(int)"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZipCode
{
public static int checkDigit(int zip)
{
    int remaining = zip;
    int sum = 0;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        sum += remaining % 10;
        remaining /= 10;
    }
    return 10 - (sum % 10);
}

public static String digitToBarCode(int digit) {
    if (digit == 1)
    {
        return ":::||";
    }
    if (digit == 2)
    {
        return "::|:|";
    }
    if (digit == 3)
    {
        return "::||:";
    }
    if (digit == 4)
    {
        return ":|::|";
    }
    if (digit == 5)
    {
        return ":|:|:";
    }
    if (digit == 6)
    {
        return ":||::";
    }
    if (digit == 7)
    {
        return "|:::|";
    }
    if (digit == 8)
    {
        return "|::|:";
    }
    if (digit == 9)
    {
        return "|:|::";
    }
    if (digit == 0)
    {
        return "||:::";
    }
    return "";

}

}
```

Tester Class is Here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZipCodeConverter
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a zip code: ");
    int zip = input.nextInt();
    int checkDigit = checkDigit(zip);
    String digitPrint=digitToBarCode(checkDigit);

        int specificNum1=(int)((zip / Math.pow(10, 5-1)) % 10);
        String swag1=digitToBarCode(specificNum1);


        int specificNum2=(int)((zip / Math.pow(10, 4-1)) % 10);
        String swag2=digitToBarCode(specificNum2);


        int specificNum3=(int)((zip / Math.pow(10, 3-1)) % 10);
        String swag3=digitToBarCode(specificNum3);


        int specificNum4=(int)((zip / Math.pow(10, 2-1)) % 10);
        String swag4=digitToBarCode(specificNum4);


        int specificNum5=(int)((zip / Math.pow(10, 1-1)) % 10);
        String swag5=digitToBarCode(specificNum5);

        String y=swag1+swag2+swag3+swag4+swag5;


    System.out.println("|"+y+digitPrint+"|");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

when you call static method of another class specified class name

```
int checkDigit = ZipCode.checkDigit(zip);
String digitPrint=ZipCode.digitToBarCode(checkDigit);
```

`cannot find symbol` because compiler cannot find a `checkDigit` method in class `ZipCodeConverter` because it's exist in  `ZipCode` class

for example in your code you have a statement `Math.pow(10, 3-1))`. `Math` is the class name and `pow()` is a static method in it .so you call it `Math.pow()`

Answer (score 0):

how you call the methods checkDigit(zip); are wrong, checkDigit(zip) is a static method so it means it is owned by that class where you create it. so,

you can access it by

```
     int checkDigit = ZipCode.checkDigit(zip);
     String digitPrint =  ZipCode.digitToBarCode(checkDigit);
```

or you can extend `ZipCode` since you are calling it inside your main which is also a static :

```
     // this will able you to call method directly
     public class ZipCodeConverter extends ZipCode{
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add teh class name in front of the method:

```
int checkDigit = checkDigit(zip);
String digitPrint=digitToBarCode(checkDigit
```

must be

```
int checkDigit = ZipCode.CcheckDigit(zip);
String digitPrint=ZipCode.digitToBarCode(checkDigit);
```